# php session opened but cannot authenticate automatically in chrome using js redirection

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, session, redirect

I cannot do an automated authentication/login via website redirection from a 3rd party website to my website.

My back-end is written in php, the front-end in js.
Hereby my analysis of the problem:

> - I can do an automatic authentication with Safari, so if I redirect my    webpage with a js script I can access to the logged-in page.
> - If I do the redirection with an application (with Process.Start) in    c# or swift (similar method), I can access to the logged-in page.
> - If I print my log from the server to js I can see that the session is    alive.
> - If I access 'manually' my Apis with Chrome and Safari with the session id provided by the server I can get the data of that session.
> - The session id in Safari stays the same, in Chrome changes!
> - yes, before the header there is a session_write_close();

How can I authenticate in Chrome?